TCP vs UDP for signal consumption
I understand the difference between TCP and UDP when it comes to reliability and packet ordering. In all my testing, I have been using a TCP test server, but it has come to my attention that most SDRs use UDP for the speed factor.
Please help me understand the difference between the protocols when it comes to consuming signals. I was under the impression that signal continuity was important for analysis, such as the FFT. If UDP has the potential to be lossy, or deliver packets out of order, would this not severely impede analysis?
For example: my application has a feature to export recent historical data as a file for later analysis. If data is received out of order, does this make frequency analysis impossible?

We have to be a bit more precise about what these SDR devices really do.
What they not do is support connecting an SDR device to the controlling PC through "the internet at large": That's not what that IP-based transport is made for.
They connect a device to a PC through a direct network cable, and, typically, at most one Ethernet switch.
There's ideally no reordering of packets here. So, the distinction whether UDP corrects that or not is meaningless – not a real problem.
The other aspect of this is that TCP doesn't solve any real-world problem:
An SDR device produces data at high rates. So, at the point where the TCP stack on the PC notices a packet is missing, there's no way that the SDR device still has the data; that packet cannot possibly be re-transmitted. TCP falls flat here – not an error that it can correct.
SDR samples are inherently a streaming problem: very few applications would benefit from packets that get delivered "later on". What is your WiFi or cellular stack going to do with data from 10ms ago? nothing; it doesn't help anymore.
Furthermore, TCP is actively harmful: while you want to be notified of missing packets, and maybe even correct the occasional "tiny-scope" packet reordering (namely, a swap of two packets that happens to some network inferface devices on occasion), what you certainly do not want is to not only miss one packet, but all following packets, because TCP does not allow for a packet to be received by the application before the previous packet was received. So, where in UDP a packet drop e.g. due to an overtasked network switch is an isolated event that an SDR application might deal with more or less gracefully, in a TCP stack everything comes to a halt. TCP makes your system less reliable, not more!
Then, latency is key in many SDR applications. The TCP nature of ACK'ing received packets puts quite some load on both the host computer (or its network card, if that supports TCP offloading) and on the network itself, unless you use a large receive window. But large TCP windows make no sense – because they'd imply large latencies when you actually need to make use of any TCP robustness features.

For example: my application has a feature to export recent historical data as a file for later analysis. If data is received out of order, does this make frequency analysis impossible?

Yes, but that's not going to be a problem: Any reasonably designed SDR device will use an on-the-wire data structure for the sample packets that will contain a sequence counter, so that the driver can either inform you of reordering and drop the "late" packet, or actually re-order itself. For example, the VITA49 radio interface standard implements a wrap-around 16 bit packet count field for exactly this reason.

Thank you for the detailed answer, this was very helpful!

"If it's late it's useless, no matter how complete." - use UDP.
"If it's not complete it's useless, no matter how prompt." - Use TCP.
